# How can i show my username and email adress on page? tank_auth codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I have a codeigniter application.
Today i added the tank_auth plugin. it works great but there is one thing i don't know. how do i print the username on the page?

In the documentation of tank_auth they say

> get_username: Get username for authenticated user, FALSE otherwise. This method is meaningless if username is not used on registration (in this case it returns an empty string for every user).\

But can is how the username in my views? and how should i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_username`.

BUT, you have to set the users username, otherwise `get_username` will return `FALSE`.

So, if you have a user, and that user is logged in, and that user has a username set (not just an email address), you can display the username via:

```
echo $this->tank_auth->get_username();
```

Comment: i get the error Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$tank_auth

Comment: fixed it. forgot to load the tank auth library in autoload.php